# Why isn't Spring rolling back on RuntimeException?

Tags: spring, transactions

I am trying to write a piece of code in which I can see an @Transaction method being rolled back upon a RuntimeException. That should be the expected default behaviour, but it is not what I am seeing.  Any ideas why?

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:mrpomario/springcore/jdbc/jdbc-testenv-config.xml")
@Transactional // Will rollback test transactions at the end
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
public class TransactionalTest
{
    @Autowired
    FeedManagerOne feedManagerOne;

    @Test
    public void test_RuntimeExceptions_Rollback_Behaviour(){
         Feed bogus = new Feed("B", "B", false);

         assertFalse(feedManagerOne.exists(bogus));

         try {
              feedManagerOne.createFeedAndThrowRuntimeException(bogus);
         }  catch (RuntimeException e) { }

         // WRONG! feedManagerOne.exists(bogus) SHOULD return false, but returns true.
         assertFalse(feedManagerOne.exists(bogus));
    }

}
```

My Service:

```
@Service
public class FeedManagerOne {
    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public boolean exists(Feed feed) {
        String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM feed WHERE name = ? AND url = ? AND is_active = ?";
        int total = jdbcTemplate.queryForInt(query, feed.getName(), feed.getUrl(), feed.isActive());
        boolean found = (total == 1);

        return found;
    }

    @Transactional
    public boolean createFeedAndThrowRuntimeException(Feed feed) {
        String query = "INSERT INTO feed (name, url, is_active) values (?, ?, ?)";
        int rowsChanged = jdbcTemplate.update(query, feed.getName(), feed.getUrl(), feed.isActive());
        boolean created = (rowsChanged == 1);

        if (true)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }

        return created;
    }
}
```

This is how I define my TransactionManager:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2">
    <jdbc:script location="mrpomario/springcore/jdbc/testdb/schema.sql"/>
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:mrpomario/springcore/jdbc/testdb/test-data.sql"/>
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's expected behaviour.

When you throw an exception (that should cause rollback) from `@Transactional` method, Spring marks transcation to be rolled back at its end. So, if you throw an exception from the top-most `@Transactional` method in the call stack, transaction will be rolled back immediately.

But in your case your test method is `@Transactional` as well, therefore you have a single transaction that spans the whole test method. It means that despite the fact that transaction is marked for rollback after calling `createFeedAndThrowRuntimeException()`, it's not rolled back until the end of the test method, therefore the second call of `exists()` can observe the changes.

So, if you want to see the rollback you need to make your test method non-transactional.

Also I don't see `<tx:annotation-driven/>` in your configuration.